# How to fix this particular error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to write the following code so that it will not return the error object reference not set .... 
Below is the code.

```
Private Quantity As String

Public Property Quantity1() As String
    Get
        Return Quantity.ToString()
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Quantity = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You don't have to call `ToString` on a `String` - redundant.

Comment: Since this is `ASPX` properties would have to store and call values from a Session variable or other data persistant route. The values are wiped clean with each postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your variables. For example...

```
 Private Quantity As String = ""
```

On another note, you do not have to add `ToString` to your strings as they are already `Strings`, it's a non-needed cast.

Answer (score 1):

May be you needs to initialize your private vars with an initial value, or where are you assigning any value to them?

```
Private Quantity As String = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the `.ToString()` calls from your properties. They are completely redundant since the variables you are returning are already strings.

Second, Strings in .net are reference types. Therefore, when you write something like `Private Quantity As String`, the `Quantity` is null (Nothing in vb.net), since it points to no string. If you wrote  `Private Quantity As String = String.Empty` then it will not be null.